# Save files downloaded in Mozilla Firefox using 'Open with' function to a specific folder

Tags: firefox, suse

I am using `Mozilla Firefox 3.5.2` installed in a `SUSE 10.3` machine.

One of my programs generates a (**`.doc`**) file and outputs me through the browser. I get a **browser pop-up** saying if you want to `Save File` or `Open With`.

When I choose the **Open With** (*Open Office Writer*) option it saves the file in `/tmp` directory.Instead of that I want to make it save in some other location say like `/home1/guest/Documents`.

I tried out few things like changing the environment variable `TMPDIR` to `/home1/guest/Documents`

Added the **`browser.cache.disk.parent_directory`** key in `about:config` and set the value to `/home1/guest/Documents` in `Mozilla Firefox`

But it still saves the files in `/tmp`, is there a workaround for this in `Mozilla Firefox`.

Comment: Even if it downloads the file into your /tmp directory, can't you just then save it to where you want after it opens it automatically in Office Writer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [DownLoadThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) FireFox extension. It will let you select any folder you want for downloading files and change the selection whenever needed.